# Is there any penalty on resurrecting dead dwellers in Fallout Shelter?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I get dead dwellers from time to time and I use to resurrect them, is there any penalty (temporal or permanent) applied to resurrected dwellers in any way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not appear that there are any additionally penalties applied to the dweller (I haven't been able to find anything). You just have to pay the revival fee.

Comment: I think the same, but I saw yesterday that my resurrected dweller had low happiness and I wondered if there could be something else

Comment: @Jade Being injured lowers happiness. They were probably injured before they died.

Comment: If a dweller dies his / her happiness drops to 0%. @Jade